# zurb-foundation 5 gem for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

Do we have something like `"zurb-foundation", "~> 4.3.2"` for rails, but for foundation version 5?

I mean a gem which could generate some files to use with the asset pipeline?

Comment: Have you tried `foundation-rails`? http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html

Answer (score 1):

The gem is now just called `foundation`

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

Comment: I know that, but does it come with the generators?

Comment: its actually now on bower so I think you'll have to use that